# Stop UILabel text change from triggering auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout

I have a ViewController's view that is initialized with AutoLayout. As part of this view, I also have an UIImageView with some constraints - 0 top, 0 left, 0 right, 300 bottom

At some point, I execute a range of animations of which some zoom in and change the center of the image

```
self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(w*s/widthDivider, h-h*s/heightDivider);
```

Everything looks fine up until I have to change some `UILabel`'s text on the page, and as I've noticed it will trigger AutoLayout which puts back my zoomed image into its initial constraints and break my layout.

```
self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 23];
```

Is there any way in which I can stop the AutoLayout trigger when changing the above label's text?

Refactoring the animations which center the image to be also based on constraints would be a solution that I have to take at a certain point if I cannot stop the AutoLayout trigger on text change.

Comment: ```self.label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO``` ?

Comment: I did try that before setting the text. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: If you are using autolayout you shouldn't modify the frame of a view directly, or it will be reset when autolayout runs again.  What you should do is alter the constraints for your imageview rather than its frame

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in the post. I read about it a lot lately and I plan on doing so at some point, but there's quite some refactoring to do and I was looking for a workaround

Comment: Maybe set the width to a biggish number - then the width is fixed and will cater for changes and maybe you won't trigger

Comment: I tried with both the width and the height and gave considerably more space than required, but it runs anyway

Comment: I have an idea - will post it as an answer, not sure it will work though ...

Comment: Doesn't add constraints with  imageView, layout it with frames ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

I added the subclass idea. Note I was able to prevent autolayout to trigger with all of these approaches.

**Using constraints**

I think it is a design issue and you'll need to do that refactoring. Below just some ideas to try. Not really preventing autolayout but trying to prevent the label from triggering it.

Once the animation is done, what if you remove or deactivate all the label's constraints. So do something like

```
// Remove all constraints
[label removeConstraints:label.constraints];
```

or

```
// Deactivate constraints
for ( NSLayoutConstraint * c in label.constraints )
{
    c.active = NO;
}
```

These will prevent the constraints from updating and that *might* prevent autolayout from triggering altogether.

**Subclassing**

I added this later. It also prevents autolayout but again your situation seems different. Anyhow, how about this. Subclass `UILabel` and override its `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` message as below. The `self.stopLayout` is a `BOOL` that I set to `YES` when I no longer want to trigger autolayout and it works nicely on this side.

```
- ( void ) invalidateIntrinsicContentSize
{
    if ( ! self.stopLayout )
    {
        super.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn t work either. I guess the only approach is to refactor it and use constraints.

Comment: Oh well, is how it goes - good luck with that. I actually think you need to check the animation. If it changes constraints correctly then this should not be a problem. The constraints should not reset after anim?

Comment: @BogdanDaniel - have a look at another approach I added to my suggestion. It might work and save you the effort of reworking your animation. It is based on subclassing ```UILabel``` and is discussed in more detail in the answer I edited.

Comment: Thank you. The latest edit works well. You save me quite a lot of refactoring and rethinking the animation.

Comment: Nice I'm glad - thanks for letting me know. That subclass is powerful and a nice option to have available.

Comment: Yes, good thing also that you got the chance to post an answer and edit it as someone had already closed the question for some reason ...